# Show that $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Let $f(x, \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} x^{\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}}$, where $0 < x < 1$ and $\theta > 0$. Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be iid with density $f$.

Taking the log likelihood, I found
$$ l(\theta) = -n\ln{\theta} + \frac{1-\theta}{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n{\ln{X_i}}  $$
$$ l'(\theta) = -\frac{n}{\theta} - \frac{1}{\theta^2}\sum{\ln{X_i}}$$

Setting $l'(\theta) = 0$ yields the MLE of $$\hat{\theta} = -\frac{1}{n}\sum{\ln(X_i)}$$

But I don't know how to show that $E(\hat{\theta}) = \theta$, i.e. it's an unbiased estimator. I tried taking the estimate of both sides as follows:

$$ E(\hat{\theta}) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum{\ln{E(X_i)}} = -\frac{1}{n}\sum{\ln{\frac{1}{1 + \theta}}} = \ln(1 + \theta)$$
where I found $E(X_i)$ as follows:

$$ E(X) = \int_0^1{x f(x, \theta) dx} = \frac{1}{\theta}\int_0^1{x^{1/\theta}} = \frac{1}{1 + \theta} x^{\frac{1 + \theta} {\theta}}{\huge\rvert}_0^1 = \frac{1}{1 + \theta}$$

---

Okay, thanks to @CommongerG for pointing out my mistake in his answer. We have 
$$E(\hat{\theta}) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum{E(\ln{X})} = -E(\ln{X})$$
So I need to show $E(\ln{X}) = -\theta$. Well,

$$ E(\ln{X}) = \int_0^1{\ln{x} f(x, \theta) dx} = \theta^{-1}\int_0^1{x^{\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}}\ln{x}dx}$$

Thank you @MlleM for pointing out my calculus error. I finally got the desired result. Letting $u = \ln{x}$ and $dv = \theta^{-1}x^{\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}} dx$, we have $du = \frac{dx}{x}$ and $v = x^{\frac{1}{\theta}}$. Then this solves as:

$$ E(\ln{X}) = x^{\frac{1}{\theta}}\ln(x){\large\rvert}_0^1 - \int_0^1{x^{\frac{1}{\theta}}dx}{\huge\rvert}_0^1 = 0 - \theta x^{\frac{1}{\theta}} {\huge\rvert}_0^1 = - \theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here: $$ln\left(E(X_i)\right)\neq E(ln(X_i))$$

$$ E(\hat{\theta}) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum{E(ln(X_i))}=-\frac{n}{n}E(ln(X_i))=-E(\ln(X_i))$$

Now you just have to show $E(\ln{X_i})=-\theta$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. In general, when is E(f(x)) = f(E(x))? I tried solving it using your correction, but I'm still not getting it to work out. Could you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: Nevermind, I found my mistake. The math works out on paper. I'm currently fixing my edit above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was just about to work it out. Glad you got it!

Comment: I apologize, but after double-checking my math, I made an error in the solution that I thought would work. I've updated my question above to show my work. Could you please take a look to see if you can find my error? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: "In general, when is $E(f(X)) = f(E(X))$?" Only when $f(x)$ is linear (or $X$ is a constant)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may be a calculus error; check what you got for $du$ and $v$.  For $v$, remember that you have to integrate $dv$, but you seem to have calculated the derivative.

Comment: Thank you! I'm kicking myself for making such an elementary calculus error.